# How do I relay an audio/video stream?

Tags: video-streaming, media, audio-streaming

I want to be able to upload an audio/video stream to a server in the building, and then any computer in the building can connect & view the stream. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**:

Okay. So the setup is this: It is my place of work, and in part of the building we have a big Auditorium with cameras, sound desk, PCs etc.  At the moment we just feed the camera into a windows PC that has Adobe Flash Media server installed, so we can broadcast the feed on to youtube.

However that is not useful for a permanent solution, as we cannot be continuously live streaming on to Youtube.  What I am imagining (although I do not know the technologies involved, but I am willing to learn) is somehow streaming the audio / video onto a machine (either in the auditorium, or in our server room) and then being able to use that stream in anyone of the rooms around the building.  Again, I am unsure of the technology needed, but I would like a way of broadcasting the stream around the building without hardwiring Audio/Visual cables to each room.

The building is fully networked with offices and servers connecting them all together.

Comment: This question is to broad. You can achieve this is a host of different ways. I suggest you do some research into media and file servers - come back if you have any specific questions should you get stuck. Thanks

Comment: I don't think the question is broad, I want options to be able to do this.  All media servers I have found so far are simply streaming a video file on the server, but I want to stream live  ideo from one room to another or all rooms in the building.

Comment: I think it would be easier for others to help if you are looking in certain technology - like are you going to implement DLNA Digital Media Server?  Or setting up a webpage like Youtube so other computers can view with browser?  Otherwise a simple Windows share may work.  Also it would be helpful to describe what did you mean by "building"... is it connected to the same network, or they belongs to different subnets?

Comment: @KennethL I have updated my question with more details, hopefully you can shed some light on the situation!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into DLNA solutions.  It is a set of standards to perform multimedia contents playback across devices over a network.

In the DLNA specifications, there are mainly three roles: Digital Media Server (DMS), Digital Media Player (DMP), Digital Media Controller (DMC).

DMS keeps all the media files, DMC is like a remote controller and DMP playback the multimedia contents.  Sometimes a device / software plays multiple roles.  e.g. there are now "smart TV" that is capable to be the DMC and DMP so that it can find and play multimedia contents on DMS on the same network.

You can install DMS software on your server and keeps all multimedia files there, and in the other rooms you can install DMP+DMC software.  To my knowledge Windows Media Player is also capable of being DMP/DMC (but I did not try it out on my own).

If you would like to play contents remotely, you can install DMC software at your control room, so that DMC sends a command to DMS to playback content at desired DMP.